# How to use LIKE "=~" with neo4j on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, neo4j

I'm using **Neo4j** with **ruby on rails** and I want to search user name with **"LIKE"** Operator **"=~"** .. with **"Where"** in **ActiveNode** to return a list of matched users.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it by using a string in `where` and then use a param for your regex. Once you start using a string in a `where` clause, you're operating in pure cypher, so http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html would be good to read.

```
Client.as(:c).where('c.name =~ {name}').params(name: '.h?ristopher')
```

If you want a shorter version, you can also do this:

```
Client.where(name: /.h?ristopher/)
```

The Cypher match it generates is nearly identical but that one won't use a param. It's less safe for your DB if you're basing your query off form data and your performance won't be as good due to the way Neo4j caches query paths.

Comment: thanks @subvertallchris , How to check two **params** with the shorter version? :D with **or**

Comment: You'd need to use the longer version at that point. `Client.as(:c).where('c.name =~ {first_regex} OR c.occupation =~ {second_regex}').params(first_regex: /regex_1/, second_regex: /second_regex')`.

Answer (score 0):

The find_by method works like the where SQL query.  [Here is the documentation.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#rewhere)

```
    Client.find_by user_name: 'Mr Smith'
    # => #<Client id: 1, user_name: "Mr Smith">

    Client.find_by user_name: 'non_user'
    # => nil
```

Comment: thanks @new2code, but i want the equivalent to
`Client.where("first_name LIKE '%#{params[:first_name]}%'")`
because database return
`"Invalid input 'I': expected 'o/O' (line 1, column 41)\n\"MATCH (result:`User`) WHERE first_name LIKE '%mOhA%' RETURN result\"\n ^"`